# UIStackView subviews don't recalculate height when something changes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uistackview

In my app, I have one UIStackView that contains two views. I want that, when one of those views disappears or grows in height, the other one adapts by occupying all the remaining space. But what happens is that is height and position remains unchanged even if I remove the other view from the UIStackView.

My views are declared this way:

```
fileprivate func initLayout() {
    subView1 = UIStackView()
    subView1.axis = .vertical
    // same for subView2
    
    container = UIStackView()
    view.addSubview(container!)
    
    container?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subView1?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subView2?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    container?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    container?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    container?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    container?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    container?.addArrangedSubview(subView1)
    container?.addArrangedSubview(subView2)
}
```

Initially, their height is correct no matter what their content is (subView1 occupies all the space that subView2 leaves). But then if I call

```
container?.removeArrangedSubview(subView2)
```

subView2 disappears, but subView1 keeps the same height and position, leaving a blank space below it. How can I make it adapt when subView2 changes?

It also happens when subView2 grows in size. Sometimes I need it to add more options. So what I was doing is adding the new views to subView2 and then calling

```
container?.removeArrangedSubview(subView1)
container?.removeArrangedSubview(subView2)
container?.addArrangedSubview(subView1)
container?.addArrangedSubview(subView2)
```

It doesn't work neither. subView1 stays the same position and height, so they overlap.

Comment: As I can see, your `container ` and `subView1 ` are both UIStackView, is that right?

Comment: Yes, and subView 2 is a UIStackView too

Comment: can you show more of you code or your description? like what attributes you add in UIStackView and what component will  you put to UIStackView.

Comment: @JOSEMAFUEN - it is ***very difficult*** to offer help when you post *"this is sort-of my code"*. Show enough code that **demonstrates** the issue. Please review [ask].